# How to reinstall Windows Boot Manager?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, windows

Is it possible that if I completely wipe my hard drive (also deleting all partitions on it) and put it to NTFS, it would bring back Windows Boot Manager. Therefore, I can install windows again?

Answer (score 2):

It is always possible to delete EVERYTHING, start from scratch, and install a new Operating System (in fact this tends to be the easiest way to install an OS). This holds for Linux, Mac OS, and Windows.

When you boot from the Windows Live Media (e.g. installation DVD) and choose an option similar to "Erase disk and install", it will delete EVERRYTHING on the disk, create NTFS partitions, install Windows, and install the Windows boot loader.

Also note that it's possible to have Windows and Ubuntu on your computer at the same time. This is called [dual boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

Comment: Is there a certain process I should follow to completely wipe everything? Because I tried and can't boot from the "Windows" installer on my thumb drive. I know the installs good, because I've used it before. But the computer says, " No Bootable Media - Please Restart Computer

Comment: @mhendrickson When you used the USB drive previously, was it on the computer in question or a different computer? It's possible this computer doesn't support booting from USB.

Comment: It was this computer, and i completely winged it last time and have no idea how i got it to work..

Comment: I just re-burned the Windows 8.1 image to a flash drive and after doing everything precisely, the computer boots and still says, "No bootable device -- Please restart systen" What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `Windows Boot Manager` can be installed and configured through the [bcdboot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824874.aspx) command in Windows or Windows installation media. It's very simple to use.

Creating new filesystems ("formatting") or partitions on the other side is completely unrelated to bootloaders and won't magically create or install them.

Answer (score 0):

http://easybcd.joydownload.com/?c=61&gclid=CP_d0NiKicICFUrpwgodbwUAig
its very good app use it to edit boot menu